# 'array bound is not an integer constant' when defining size of array in class, using an element of a const array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constants

```
#ifndef QWERT_H
#define QWERT_H

const int x [] = {1, 2,};
const int z = 3;
#endif


#include <iostream>
#include "qwert.h"
class Class   
{  
    int y [x[0]];  //error:array bound is not an integer constant
    int g [z];     //no problem  
};


int main ()  
{  

    int y [x[0]];      //no problem
    Class a_class;

}
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. Other people with this problem seem to be trying to dynamically allocate arrays. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but `#ifndef QWERT_H` should appear _only_ in qwert.h, and `#include "qwert.h"` should _not_ appear in qwert.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main version works because your compiler has an extension to allow for variable length arrays. Array accesses cannot be constant expressions in C++03, even if the array and the index are both constant expressions, which is the source of the error.

Answer (score 4):

x is const (as is z obviously), but x[0] is not a constant expression.  Array declarations in a class definition must have constant size specifiers.

Consider this for a moment; how would you expect the sizeof operator to evaluate the size of your class if it contains an array of unknown size at compile time?

Comment: x[0] **is** const. it's not constant expression though.

Comment: x[0] is a read-only location in this case. Try to assign a value to x[0] and you'll get a compile-time "assignment of read-only location"

Comment: Yeah i see. I didn't realize there was a potential distinction between constant expressions and mere read-only-locations/consts, or that x[0] would constitute the latter. I guess the problem is that array access takes place too late in compilation for it to be allowed as a constant expression?  PS. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @user574733: It's an "that's just how it is" issue rather than there being any fundamental technical reason (such as you hint at with "takes place too late").

Comment: @user574733: For another example that may help, consider: "extern int const x; int a[x];". Even though x is an int const, it cannot (yet) be used in an integer constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an array must be a *constant expression*.  I don't believe that constant elements in an array qualify as such.

The version in main() working is probably due to a compiler extension.